# Is creating an app of a drinking game prohibited?

Tags: practical-islam

Assalam o Alaikum,

I am an iPhone app developer. Recently, I was assigned to create an app of a drinking game (namely [Beer Pong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer_pong)). When I searched about it, I found that it is a [drinking game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_game). It is easily understandable that playing this game is prohibited in Islam. My question is that **Is it also prohibited to be a part of such type of project i-e creating an iPhone app of this type of game?**.

*Note: The app doesn't contain any involvement of Beer/Drinking but since the purpose of creating this app is to promote this game.*

Answer (score 1):

Walaikum Salam

I'm no expert. However, lets say you have been assigned to create a website containing pornographic content and you would not have to see the "stuff" yourself. Would it be prohibited?

Even if we sometimes can't decide if it is harram or halal we should think about the ethics in Islam. We should avoid promoting, helping and selling  harram things to Muslims or non-muslims.

But this is my opinion. You should find a scholar and ask him. It could differ in opinions of the different Islamic "schools".

Answer (score 0):

Assalamou alaykoum,

of course brother, it is forbidden, let your work and your earnings stay halal and ethical by avoiding everything concerning alcohol, porc, gambling, nudity, etc.